# Electrical breaker and outlet wiring question

Tags: electrical

I want to run a dedicated circuit for my air compressor. Can I run a 20 amp breaker with 12-2 to a single 20 amp receptacle for an air compressor?

Comment: What make/model is your breaker panel, and what size feeder do you have going to it?  What sort of space is this dedicated outlet living in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should first [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how to best participate here with upvotes for helpful answers and checks for accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a 20A breaker and 12-2 copper (with ground, but that's a given unless you have found some antique wire) to a single 20A receptacle for **any** purpose. Including an air compressor.

However, for an air compressor "dedicated circuit" the FIRST question I'd ask is whether the motor can be converted to run on 240V, and if it can, I'd strongly suggest doing that unless you have strong reasons not to (such as this being a portable compressor that you often take to job sites where 240V is hard to come by.)

If that is the case, I'd then look at provisioning a 240V (two-pole) breaker of appropriate amperage to a 240V outlet of the appropriate amperage rating on appropriate size wire for that amperage (or 12/2 if you are already sitting on it, even if it's larger than needed for 240V and fewer amps.) Rewire the compressor for 240V operation and install the matching plug.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 12/2 (plus ground) to a dedicated 20A receptacle.

I don't know if is adequate for the specs of the compressor.

Answer (score 0):

12/2 w/ground is fine but you want to check the service rating on your compressor. More than likely a 20 amp circuit will handle it. The other consideration is if you're running it to an indoor or outdoor receptacle. Anything outdoors has to be rated for weather.
Also, if you're adding a breaker make sure it's compatible with your main panel and you follow code. i.e. GFCI or AFCI beaker.